# Chainlink node is not triggering job based on an external adapter

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I’m having troubles with making a local custom adapter to work: my node seems to not react to the logs it receives and the job using my adapter is not triggered.

Some points I have been careful about:

- My consumer contract and node are funded with both `LINK` and `ETH`
- My adapter name is understood by the node and the `.toml` job is validated
- My oracle is deployed and well set in my `.toml` job definition
- Fulfillment permissions are set up for the oracle with the correct node address
- Both oracle address and `jobId` are correct when making the request from the consumer contract
- I have ensured that my node has both
  `UNRESTRICTED_NETWORK_ACCESS` and `ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_ADAPTERS` variables set to `true`
- The fee definition seems correct in the consumer contract definition, as it follows the `ATestnetConsumer.sol` [example](https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/).

The exemplary contract `ATestnetConsumer.sol` works well with the node. Requests are made and responses are returned to the oracle and then the consumer contract.

I also made a webhook job version which uses my custom adapter and it works well. Still, making call from my own consumer contract for a job using my custom adapter triggers no job on the node.

When the chainlink request is made, `LINK` is being payed by the consumer contract and logs are received by the node:

```
2022-02-01T14:19:39Z [DEBUG] LogBroadcaster: Received a log log/broadcaster.go:324 address=ORACLE_ADDRESS_IS_CORRECT_HERE blockHash=0x8057122669ab1fc78f44920e1910e9a17f2cbfaa59bf94d2d2a1588eaaeff5db blockNumber=29
```

No error message pops up. The node seems to process as much logs as there has been request from my consumer (9 here), but does not proceed with any job runs:

```
2022-02-01T14:39:27Z [INFO] LogBroadcaster: Finished async backfill of 9 logs  log/eth_subscriber.go:155
```

The adapter is hosted within a container. The url set up for is: `http://host.docker.internal:5000/auth` (`host.docker.internal` stands for localhost). I also tried `localhost` and `0.0.0.0` as hosts. Because my webhook is successful I do not expect troubles for the node to access it. Also, my adapter/webserver logs show no interaction coming from the node (since no job is triggered).

What am I missing here? What additional steps should I take?

My chainlink node version is `0.10.15` (otherwise UI problems with versions 1.0.x). My Oracle contract uses chainlink `v0.6` and my chainlink client is `v0.8` (for both example `ATestnetConsumer.sol` and my contract.

Node `.env` file:

```
ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=42
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=CORRECT_LINK_ADDRESS
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
MIN_INCOMING_CONFIRMATIONS=1
FEATURE_WEBHOOK_V2=true
ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_ADAPTERS=true
DEFAULT_HTTP_ALLOW_UNRESTRICTED_NETWORK_ACCESS=true
CHAINLINK_DEV=true
BLOCK_BACKFILL_SKIP=true
```

Bridge info:

```
Name    adapter-name
URL http://host.docker.internal:5000/auth
Confirmations   0
Minimum Contract Payment    0
Outgoing Token  some_outgoing_token
```

Job definition:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "some-name"
contractAddress = "ORACLE_ADDRESS_IS_CORRECT_HERE"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="bridge" name="my-adapter" requestData="{\\"data\\": {\\"lichess_token\\": $(decode_cbor.apiToken)}}"]
    parse_acc    [type=jsonparse path="data,verified" data="$(fetch)"]
    parse_accid  [type=jsonparse path="data,url" data="$(fetch)"]
    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode 
                  abi="(uint256 requestIdx, bool accountVerified, bytes accountId)" 
                  data="{ \\"requestIdx\\": $(decode_cbor.requestIdx), \\"accountVerified\\": $(parse_acc), \\"accountId\\": $(parse_accid) }"
                 ]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="ORACLE_ADDRESS_IS_CORRECT_HERE" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse_acc -> parse_accid -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
externalJobID = "27cd13da-85cd-44b1-8851-78500663ffa0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the solution.

The string to bytes conversion I used for the `jobId` was seemingly erroneous. Strangely, this is the same which is given within the `ATestnetConsumer.sol` example. Yet, it was not outputting an interpretable `jobId` for the node.

The `stringToBytes32` function:

```
  function stringToBytes32(string memory source) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
      return 0x0;
    }

    assembly { // solhint-disable-line no-inline-assembly
      result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
  }
```

What I did instead was hardcode the `jobId` within the contract constructor and with type `bytes32`, instead of converting the string given in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [@pedropedro](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/93141/pedropedro)

Sounds like it could be a something in docker config.
The node works, the adapter works on a webhook job, but not through a normal job on the node.

I suggest you to review very carefully the docker config.

Comment: Thanks Solange for this suggestion :) I eventually found the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

When calling `requestEthereumPrice` at the client contract, just make sure you are passing the job id without the dashes (i.e. externalJobID = `"27cd13da85cd44b1885178500663ffa0"`), otherwise job id will not fit into a `bytes32` type.

That is probably why your function `stringToBytes32()` output was not what you expected